# using c# generics extension methods to operate on a class and not a collection

Tags: c#, linq, generics, extension-methods

```
I have the following types defined:
-----------------------------------

interface IMyInterface<T> where T : class
{
   void BlahBlah();
}
abstract class MyBase<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : class
{
   public abstract T MyInfo { get; set; }
   public abstract T MyInfo2 { get; set; }
   public void BlahBlah()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(MyInfo + ", " + MyInfo2);
   }
}
class MyConcreteClass1<T> : MyBase<T> where T : class
{
   public override T MyInfo { get; set; }
   public override T MyInfo2 { get; set; }
}
class MyConcreteClass2<T> : MyBase<T> where T : class
{
   public override T MyInfo { get; set; }
   public override T MyInfo2 { get; set; }
}


public static class DataOperations<T, U> where T : class where U : class
{
        public static U Operate(this T source, U destination)
        {
            var sourceProps = source.GetType().GetProperties();
            var destinationProps = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

                .
                .
                .
            return destination;
        }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to do in the implementation is to operate on two of the above classes as so:

```
MyConcreteClass1<String> class1 = new MyConcreteClass1<String>();
class1.MyInfo = "Some Value";
class1.MyInfo2 = "another value";
MyConcreteClass2<String> class2 = new MyConcreteClass2<String>();
var c2 = class1.Operate(class2);
```

The problem is that I get:
"CS1106 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class" on DataOperations class name.

Comment: Is it that you don't understand the error or don't know what to do to fix things up so they work how you want?

Comment: Didn't know how to fix it, because I had forgotten that you can add the type constraints instead on the method rather than the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaring type must be be non-generic, but the *method* can be generic. Consider instead:

```cs
public static class DataOperations
{
        public static U Operate<T, U>(this T source, U destination)
             where T : class where U : class
        { // ...
        }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I forgot that you can do the same thing on the method name as you can on the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Move the generic definitions onto the method:

```
public static class DataOperations
{
        public static U Operate<T, U>(this T source, U destination)  where T : class where U : class
        {
            // Whatever
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods have to be defined - as the error states - in a **non-generic** static (top-level) class.

So you need to make the `DataOperations` class non-generic and the method itself generic instead:

```
public static class DataOperations
{
        public static U Operate<T, U>(this T source, U destination) where T : class where U : class

        {
            var sourceProps = source.GetType().GetProperties();
            var destinationProps = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

                .
                .
                .
            return destination;
        }
}
```